# Is there any way to upload directory with Tags for all the files using Multiple File Upload Interface to s3 Bucket - aws sdk

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Is there any way to upload a directory with Tags for all the files using MultipleFileUpload Interface - AWS SDK

I am able to upload the directory with all the files to s3 bucket,but not able to find proper references to add tags to all the sub-files inside the directory while uploading it to s3 bucket

Code :

```
TransferManager xfer_mgr = TransferManagerBuilder.standard().withS3Client(getAmazonS3Client()).build();

             MultipleFileUpload xfer = xfer_mgr.uploadDirectory(getStorageName(),
                     trgtFolder, srcfolder, true);
       
             XferMgrProgress.showTransferProgress(xfer);
         
             XferMgrProgress.waitForCompletion(xfer);
```

any reference for adding the tags for all sub files in the directory using MultipleFileUpload upload directory would be help

Answer (score 0):

The [uploadDirectory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html#uploadDirectory-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.io.File-boolean-com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.ObjectMetadataProvider-com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.ObjectTaggingProvider-) method has an overload that accepts an `ObjectTaggingProvider` callback:

> taggingProvider - A callback of type ObjectTaggingProvider which is used to provide the tags for each file being uploaded.

The following example would apply a list of tags to every file being uploaded:

```
MultipleFileUpload upload = transferManager.uploadDirectory("myBucket", "myKey", new File("/path/to/dir"), true, null, context -> new ObjectTagging(List.of(new Tag("key", "value"))));
```